# Parsing argument to MSDeploy from MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy

I have just started playing with TeamCity and its great. Now I got it to deploy to my staging server after a commit so I always know I have the latest version running there. ( The idea was borrowed from: http://www.agileatwork.com/automatic-deployment-from-teamcity-using-webdeploy/ )

But as the site generates some files which I dont want to wipe out on every publish I found the parameter to MSDeploy

```
-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
```

But how do I append this to MSBuild command

```
MSBuild.exe MvcApplication1.sln 
 /p:Configuration=Debug 
 /p:OutputPath=bin 
 /p:DeployOnBuild=True 
 /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
 /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://ss-iis:8172/MSDeploy.axd 
 /p:username=user
 /p:password=pass
 /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
 /p:DeployIisAppPath=foo.bar.tld 
 /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
```

Can this be done?

Or is there are a more fancy way of doing automatic web deployments from TeamCity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be `/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=true` that you want.